# Multiple errors occurred during the input validation on Linkedin API

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm getting this response

```json
{
    "message": "Multiple errors occurred during the input validation. Please see errorDetails for more information.",
    "status": 400
}
```

Tried in multiple ways but there is no `errorDetails` key.

The Linkedin's API is a shame. I have tried to create an Inline creative, by following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads/account-structure/create-and-manage-creatives?view=li-lms-2023-11&tabs=http%2Chttp-update-a-creative

There could be missing one parameter, but without providing `errorDetails` I must spend days of tests.

Solution. Maybe someone knows how to extend the error response.